# Loading/Unloading Select2 cleanly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

My page loads within a portlet-like application on which I have no control. My page is rendered within a portlet content pane when I click a link on the menu of the portlet application.

Scripts that have been declared within the JSP file get loaded properly.
I am creating dynamic select elements on my page and applying the Select2 plugin on them.

For Select2, I have observed the following issues (which I can't create a fiddle for...or don't know how to create).

When the portlet loads my page in the content pane via ajax the first time, everything works fine.
When I reload the page (still ajax), I get the following error:

`$selectBox.select2 is not a function`

I presumed this may be because there might be an extra instance of Select2 getting created on my page.

Therefore I added the following statement in my page (before the script tag for select2)

`window.Select2 = undefined;`

Now, the select2 plugin loads fine. However, when I click on a drop-down and click anywhere else on the page, I would expect the drop-down to close, but I get the following error on the console

`TypeError: self is undefined`

Is there a better way of solving this problem?
How do I cleanly remove "Select2" from my page before loading it again?

Comment: show ur code instead of part of it

Comment: @Se0ng11: There isn't any select2 code to show. I create a dynamic "Select" element and simply call `selectBox.select2()` on it. That's about it.

Comment: maybe you can try to create fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ and show it here

Comment: @Se0ng11: I don't know how I could write a function that could simulate how the portlet loads my page. I can write an example on how the select2 is used on my page; but the fiddle won't show the issue that occurs. It works fine on fiddle.